# Walmart scraping (crawling) code

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to make a Walmart Scraper, where I have to scrape the title, link, image URL, price, category and subcategory of the product.

Now my approach is that I will collect seed pages for each department, like a link of USB drives from computer from electronics departments. Likewise that there are so many of them.

Now the problem is, I have kept all the seed links into one list (I use for loop to iterate over that list).  I have to extract product information from each page (so am using a `for` loop to request the URL for each page).  The last `for` loop extracts the information from the list and puts it into the XML file.

How can I optimize this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
import time
import unicodedata
import xmlcreator

xml=xmlcreator
xml.rootC('database')
xml.sub1C('product')
xml.sub2('ptitle','price','purl','urlimage','categ','subcateg')

urllist=[["http://www.walmart.com/browse/computer-accessories/usb-flash-drives/3944_3951_132959_529295?tab_value=online&catNavId=%3Cc%3aout+value%3d%27%26lt%3bc%3aout+value%3d%27%26lt%3bc%3aout+value%3d%27132959%27%2f%26gt%3b%27%2f%26gt%3b%27%2f%3E&ss=false&ic=32_0",'Electronics','USB Flash Drives']]

for i in range(0,len(urllist)):
    print 'Scrapping '+urllist[i][0]+' in '+urllist[i][1]+' Category and '+urllist[i][2]+' subcategory.......'
    count=0
    err=[]
    url=urllist[i][0]
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.add_header('UserAgent', 'Ruel.ME Walmart Scraper')
    htmlFile = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    data = htmlFile.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
    y=soup.find_all("span",class_="floatLeft numResults mt5")
    y=re.findall('<span class="floatLeft numResults mt5">(.*)</span>',str(y[0]))
    y=y[0].strip('Results');
    y=int(y)

    for k in range(0,(y/32)):
        print 'Scapping Page '+str(k)+' of '+str(y/32)+'......'
        try:
            request = urllib2.Request(url)
            request.add_header('UserAgent', 'Ruel.ME Walmart Scraper')
            htmlFile = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            data = htmlFile.read()
            soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
            purl=[]
            ptitle=[]
            pimg=[]
            price=[]
        except urllib2.URLError:
            print 'Error in Opening this url'
            continue

        for a in soup.find_all("a",class_="prodLink ListItemLink"):
            var=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', a.text).encode('ascii','ignore')
            var=var.replace('&','')
            ptitle.append(var)
            var1=re.findall('<a class=.*? href="(.*)" onclick=.*?',str(a))
            var1='http://www.walmart.com'+var1[0]
            purl.append(var1)

        for img in soup.find_all("img",class_="prodImg"):
            temp=re.findall('src="([^"]+)"',str(img))
            pimg.append(temp[0])


        for it in soup.find_all("div",class_="ItemShelfAvail"):
             var=re.findall('<span class="bigPriceText2">.*</span>',str(it))
             if not var:
                 var=re.findall('<span class="bigPriceTextOutStock2">.*</span>',str(it))
            try:
                ne=BeautifulSoup(var[0])
                z=ne.find_all("span",class_="bigPriceText2")
                if not z:
                    z=ne.find_all("span",class_="bigPriceTextOutStock2")
                    temp=z[0]
                z=re.findall('<span class="bigPriceText2">(.*)</span>',str(z[0]))
                if not z:
                    z=re.findall('<span class="bigPriceTextOutStock2">(.*)</span>',str(temp))
                z=z[0]
                w=ne.find_all("span",class_="smallPriceText2")
                if not w:
                    w=ne.find_all("span",class_="smallPriceTextOutStock2")
                    temp=w[0]
                w=re.findall('<span class="smallPriceText2">(.*)</span>',str(w[0]))
                if not w:
                    w=re.findall('<span class="smallPriceTextOutStock2">(.*)</span>',str(temp))
                w=w[0]
                prc=z+w
                price.append(prc)
            except IndexError:
                err.append(count)
                price.append('')
            count=count+1

        for j in range(0,len(ptitle)):
            if j not in err:
                xml.createOne(ptitle[j],price[j],purl[j],pimg[j],urllist[i][1],urllist[i][2])

        ln=len(url)
        url=url[0:(ln-1)]+str((k+1)*32)

xml.cls()
```

Is there a way that I can do this without collecting seed links, or do I need to collect them?

And how can I optimize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things I noticed, though I have to say I'm still a novice as well ;-)

Iterating over a list doesn't require you to iterate over a counter:

```
for i in range(0,len(urllist)):
for url in urllist:
```

Try to follow [pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as a guide when starting (use Pycharm or a pep8 plug-in for whatever text editor you're using to automatically check for this). It consists of rules for naming your variables, functions, the proper amount of whitespace etc. to increase readability, for example:

```
xml=xmlcreator
xml = xmlcreator
```

Try to use more descriptive variable names (note that I'm not fond of lower_case variable naming and instead prefer mixed case as I have an R background):

```
count=0
complProducts = 0
err=[] = 0 
numErrors = 0
y = int(y)
numListPages = # (add code here)
purl = []
productPageURLs []
```

Furthermore, try to split up the code into multiple functions each doing their own thing. This reduces the amount of code in nested loops, making the overall process more readable. You're doing:

Determining a base query page

Looping over all pages of this query, scraping it for product URLs

Having a list of product URLs, loop over them and scrape additional info

For example:

```
def scrapeListPage: 
    """Take a walmart query page and return a list of product URLs"""


def scrapeProductPage:
    """Take a product page URL and return a dictionary with additional info (price, type etc.)
etc.
```

Then I've seen the following happen quite often: define everything in functions, and then add the following at the end of your script. This code is run once the python script is run (read up on google to see how/why). This allows someone like me to follow exactly what you want to do, in what order.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Code to execute when running this script here.
```